# Drag & Drop without removal from owner

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I am using on a LinearLayout with three TextViews Drag&Drop to move it to another container.
My code:

```
OnDragListener dragi = new OnDragListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onDrag(View arg0, DragEvent arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int action = arg1.getAction();
                switch (action) {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:

                break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:

                break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:

                break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

                View view = (View) arg1.getLocalState();
                  ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                  owner.removeView(view);
                  //
                  LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) arg0;
                  container.addView(view);
                  view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                  }
                  break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:

                  break;
                default:
                  break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        };
```

My Problem is that i dont want to remove the view from the base container, it should stay there and just add a copy to the second container.

Thx

Comment: Its not that easy -->java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: i think the problem is that view can only have on parent. I also dont know a way to "clone" a view

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A view can only have one parent at any given moment, what you can do is on your drag, instead of dropping the view into the new container create a clone of the view and add that on to the new container.

To clone a view: if your view => Button called myButton, then you can do this:

```
Button myButtonClone = new Button(context);
myButtonClone.setText(myButton.getText());
```

You will have a clone of the original button. This applies to every other property, if you want to make a clone of an ImageView simply create a new one and set its drawable to be the same one as the first ImageView..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clone it, than new created view will ask for a parent view. Because a child can have at most one direct parent that's way you have to assign a same or different parent to it.

Here is some google description :

> When you start a drag, you include both the data you are moving and metadata describing this data as part of the call to the system. During the drag, the system sends drag events to the drag event listeners or callback methods of each View in the layout. The listeners or callback methods can use the metadata to decide if they want to accept the data when it is dropped. If the user drops the data over a View object, and that View object's listener or callback method has previously told the system that it wants to accept the drop, then the system sends the data to the listener or callback method in a drag event

[Please read this for detail. It will help you alot....](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html#DesignDragOperation)

> With the Android drag/drop framework, you can allow your users to move data from one View to another View in the current layout using a graphical drag and drop gesture. The framework includes a drag event class, drag listeners, and helper methods and classes.

This is summery of it. If you want to remains the view in existing parent just make a copy in the same parent and make it visibility GONE or whatever your need is.